# Does the negative ground amperage rating matter?

Tags: electrical, audio

[image]
[image]
I am looking at replacing a knackered stereo (newer model) with the closest I could find, but the current model says 5 A negative ground while the replacement says 14 A negative ground.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negative ground bit just tells you that you will be able to install it in your vehicle without having to do anything clever to isolate it. Most cars are negative ground, meaning the chassis (ground) is connected to the battery's negative terminal.

The only challenge you have with the new stereo drawing 14A rather than 5 is that you'll need to upgrade the fuse to one over 14A, as it will blow a 5A fuse. Assuming you don't have loads of uprated electrics, your battery should cope just fine with this, but you can look at running a separate power line to stereo if needs be.

When I last upgraded my car stereo I ran separate power to my new power amp, and had a 30A inline fuse - avoiding the existing fuse box entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your help 